# Aspose.Cells - Sign VBA Project in .Net Core

Tags: excel, vba, .net-core, aspose, aspose-cells

I'm referring to the same question in the aspose support forum:
https://forum.aspose.com/t/sign-vba-project-on-net-core-api/208463

Some Context, I’m working on an application with **.NetCore 2.2** with the NuGet version of the Aspose.Cells Version=**“20.1.0”**.

In this project I Create from scratch a new Workbook with

```cs
var workbook = new Workbook();
```

The problems comes when I try to Sign the VBA Project:

```cs
var cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\\somepatj\\SampleCert.pfx", "1234");
var digitalSignature = new Aspose.Cells.DigitalSignatures.DigitalSignature(cert, "Signed by Exporter System", DateTime.Now);
workbook.VbaProject.Sign(digitalSignature);
```

Now this code throws a ***System.NotImplementedExeption*** with the message: **“The method or operation is not implemented.”** in the last line.

I also tried to open a workbook instead of creating one, with

```cs
var workbook = new Workbook("Path to workbook")
```

and then try to sing the VBA project and it's the same.

In the link to the Support Forum they send me a Sample certificate with a sample book and it's the same if I try to open it and sing it with the sample certificate.

I'm starting to believe it's the .Net Core API

I'm out of ideas here, please help!

---

**Update**

They answer me in the aspose forum. It seems that the VBA Project Signature is not supported in .Net Core. 

They created the issue CELLSNETCORE-49 - Sign VBA Project on .Net Core API.

You can trace it in the link above

Comment: Yes, once the feature ("Sign VBA Project on .Net Core API") is supported, you will be informed.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Yes, you answer my question in the forum. Love your support and commitment even here on stack overflow, thanks a lot!